# Edit items in a listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello I'm trying to edit items in a listview and database

I tried to change the name and firstname with the id in the Update method in my databasehelper but it doesn't work

This is my `EditUser` class

```
public class EditUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button bouton_modifier, bouton_supprimer;
    private EditText nom, prenom;

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private String selectedName,selectedFName,selectedID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_user);
        bouton_modifier = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bouton_modifier);
        bouton_supprimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bouton_Supprimer);
        nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
        prenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prenom);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

        selectedID = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("ID");
        selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
        selectedFName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("fname");

        nom.setText(selectedName);
        prenom.setText(selectedFName);

        bouton_modifier.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = nom.getText().toString();
                String Fname = prenom.getText().toString();
                if(!name.equals("") && !Fname.equals("")){
                    mDatabaseHelper.Update(name, Fname, selectedID, selectedName, selectedFName);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EditUser.this, PageUser.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    toastMessage("You must enter a name");
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is my `DatabaseHelper` class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL3 = "FNAME";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "NAME TEXT, FNAME TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String Name, String FName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, Name);
        contentValues.put(COL3, FName);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void Update(String newName, String newFName,String id, String oldName, String oldFName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 + COL3 +
                " = '" + newName + newFName +"' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + COL3 + " = '" + oldName + oldFName + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

I would like to change the name and firstname when I click on the button "modifier" and return in the userlist page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `execSQL()` command try using the `update()` command.

The `update()` method takes the following arguments

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

So change your `Update` method in `DatabaseHelper` like this -

```
public void Update(String newName, String newFName,String id, String oldName, String oldFName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL2,newName);
    cv.put(COL3,newFName);
    String whereClause = COL1 + "=? AND " + COL2 + "=? AND " + COL3 + "=?";
    String[] args = new String[]{id, oldName,oldFName};
    db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,whereClause,args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly whats going on, but your update query seems incorrect, you have to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET column_1 = new_value_1,
    column_2 = new_value_2
WHERE
    search_condition
```

Also, it's not a problem, but after editing it, i think you might just call finish() instead of creating a new intent, unless you're removing PageUser from the stack.